Does no-cloning imply zero capacity of antidegradable channels?
I read that (paraphrasing, see below) "antidegradable channels have zero capacity because of the no-cloning theorem". Is there a formal derivation of the capacity of an antidegradable channel that uses the no-cloning theorem as one of its steps?
For context, here is the proof I'm familiar with:
Let $|\psi\rangle_{RA}\in RA$ be an initial bipartite state, and say that the channel $\mathcal{N}$ has isometric extension $V_{\mathcal{N}}: A \rightarrow BE$. Define the state $|\phi\rangle_{RBE}:= I_R\otimes V_{\mathcal{N}}|\psi\rangle_{RA}$. If $\mathcal{N}$ is antidegradable, then there exists an antidegrading map $\mathcal{T}$ with isometric extension $V_{\mathcal{T}}: E \rightarrow B'E'$ such that $\rho_{B} = \rho_{B'}$. Then the identity
$$
I(R\rangle B)_\phi = \frac{1}{2}[I(R\!:\!B)_\phi - I(R\!:\!E)_\phi]
$$
along with the use of $V_{\mathcal{T}}^\dagger$ gives $I(R\rangle B)_\phi=0$, where $I(R\rangle B)_\phi:= -H(R|B)_\phi$ is the coherent information. This implies the desired result.
In this proof, by applying $V_{\mathcal{T}}$ there may be two subsystems $B, B'$ containing the same reduced state and that is perfectly valid by the problem definition - it is not a proof by contradiction. Instead, this scenario implies that the state $\rho_B$ (loosely) cannot contain quantum information about $R$. I can't see how no-cloning can be used to make such an information theoretic claim.

Edit: For more context, I think the statement I saw was this quote from (Karumanchi, 2016):

It is well-known that the quantum capacity of antidegradable channels is zero, by the familiar cloning argument: Namely, if an anti-degradable channel were to have positive quantum capacity, F can apply the degrading map followed by the same decoder as B and thus A would be transmitting the same quantum information to B and F . This is in contradiction to the no-cloning theorem as observed in [3].

The part I don't understand is: "A would be transmitting the same quantum information to B and F". An antidegradable channel still definitely allows me to prepare two copies of the same transmitted state. And so, intuitively this should mean that there was no quantum information in that state. But I can't figure out how no-cloning converts that intuition into an actual capacity value.
Ref [3] in that quote points to (Bennett, 1997), where they analyze the erasure channel and argue that by no cloning, quantum capacity must be zero for erasure probability greater than 1/2. In contrast with antidegradable channels, this argument (which uses no-cloning to create a contradiction) is perfectly clear to me. Indeed, the authors specifically mention avoiding no-cloning arguments in analyzing the capacity of a dephasing channel.

If you assume toward contradiction that the capacity is positive, then with $N$ copies of the channel for some (possibly large) value of $N$ you can transmit an unknown qubit with fidelity as close to one as you wish. By the assumption that the channel is anti-degradable you'll also be able to recover the same unknown qubit from the environment. With a statement of the no-cloning theorem that bounds approximate cloning, it seems like that should do it (though one should never trust a proof without writing it out carefully, and I haven't done that).

A no-cloning argument for vanishing capacity of anti-degradable channels is given in the proof of Theorem 3.3 in these notes by Alexander Müller-Hermes.

That seems like what I was looking for, thanks.
